# Mycelium: Restore backup from Android to iOS

Tags: wallet-import, private-key-import, mycelium-wallet

I used Mycelium wallet on Android quite a while ago. I created a printed backup which consists of a 15-character password and two QR codes: The bitcoin address and the encrypted private key.

Meanwhile I switched to iOS, installed the iOS app and wanted to import my old wallet (which still contains Bitcoins). However, when I open the app and select "Restore from backup" it asks me to enter my *Master Seed separated by spaces*.

Sure enough, the backup does not contain a master seed and and entering the 15 character password does not work.

How to import the old wallet?

Answer (score 2):

After lots of suffering I managed to do it. Very unfortunately mycelium does not even support importing their old keys.

Fortunately they provide a backuputil which converts the private key in their format into WIF (Wallet Import Format): https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet/tree/master/backuputil

I takes some effort to built this tool but afterwards you obtain the private key in WIF format. This in turn can be entered in the new Mycelium on iOS.

Again, very unfortunately, the key is NOT imported but rather the funds transfered to the Mycelium account. This results again in unnecessary transfer fees.

Comment: May I know how you built this tool. I am basically in the same situation and would very much appreciate help.